# Skip test when exception occurs

Tags: java, junit

I have a number of tests that requires external web pages to pass. Ocassionally though the web pages time out and cause my tests to fail.

Is it possible in Junit to skip these tests if say a HTTPException occurs and warn the user, rather than failing the the test and my travis build entirely.
I've looked at using a conditional ignore but I'd rather not query the web page twice a 
Here's an example of a test:

```
@Test
public void testScrapePageAuthorDetection21()
        throws UrlAlreadyInSystemException, BannedUrlException,
        IOException, DriverException, RelativeUrlException,
        HomePageException {

    String href = "http://www.20minutos.es/deportes/noticia/candidatura-madrid-juegos-olimpicos-demasiado-pronto-2316527/0/";
    // Query the URL above
    // sometimes this will fail, 
}
```

Comment: IMO automated tests relying on external sources are never the best way to do it (depending on what you're doing). Would it be possible to get the html from all of those pages, save them & then let the test use these? You could update those html-docs each day/week simply by using a TimerSessionBean :)

Comment: Notwithstanding Seth's pertinent comment, the solution is simple: catch and swallow the exception. JUnit does nothing fancier than catching exceptions thrown in test methods.

Comment: @AndyTurner True, I just searched for similar questions & that is what's suggested to do in this case :) (Meaning it's a duplicate)